# Get similar consecutive rows as a different group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this -

```
------
| lines|
------
A
------
A
------
A
------
B
------
B
------
A
------
A
------
C
------
C
```

I need to find the count and name of the groups with similar rows, for example - The returned count of elements in the group and also the value that is in it.

For example, in the above example, the output should be -

```
3 - {"A"}
2 - {"B"}
2 - {"A"}
2 - {"C"}
```

Please note, all "A"s cannot be grouped together as "B" came in between. So, when the row values change, it forms a group but if the values return later(like "A" here), then it should be considered as a separate group.

*My approaches -*

I tried to do it using 3 ways - Using the **dictionary**, **index shift()** method, **groupby()**. The only issue is, the will consider and all "A"s as same, so would return 5 instead of 3 and 2 as separate group.

Can anyone help, thanks.

Comment: instead on index.shift, look at and use series.shift as a grouper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `groupby`, grouping by whether the `line` is the same as the `line` below (using `shift`):

```
result = (
    df.groupby(["lines", (df.lines != df.lines.shift()).cumsum()], sort=False)
    .size()
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
)

>>> result
lines
A    3
B    2
A    2
C    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Accepting in a while, the window hasn't opened yet.

Comment: Just a quicky followup question - I got the "lines" series, how could I access the first part and second part separately ? Like {"A","B","A","C"} as one series and the values {3,2,2,2} as another series. Can you please help with this too?

Comment: `result = result.reset_index(name='values')`